# Pandas HDFStore and copying to memory

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I had a

```
store = pd.HDFStore('cache/cache.h5')
```

and I have a stored DataFrame `store['myDF']`

If, in my code, I do:

```
a = store['myDF']
```

and perform operations on `a`, am I manipulating something that is now in memory or still on disk? Do I need to make an explicit copy to memory?

Answer (score 0):

`a = store['myDF']` creates a copy in memory. Manipulating the copy will not alter what is on disk. You need to manually put the copy into the store for that.